# Как в PHPStorm создавать тему для WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm

Установил OpenServer. Установил `wordpress`. Подключил его в PHPStorm. Выглядит сейчас вот таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что ни ищу руководства в интернете по запросам наподобие: phpstorm создание темы wordpress, то мне выдаёт результаты о создании плагинов для ВП.

Как в PHPStorm создавать тему для WordPress?

---

Пока писал вопрос, то понял что на этом этапе создания проекта в PHPStorm указывается, что создаваться будет именно плагин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выходит, что для разработки темы `wordpress` в PHPStorm просто можно установить ВП в какую-то папку, а потом просто её открыть через PHPStorm? И в этом вся магия?

В общем, **как в PHPStorm создавать тему для WordPress?**

Comment: магия в том, что PHPStorm будет подсвечивать тебе функция из WP. Можно кстати открыть тему, а в настройках указать путь к WP и будет тоже самое

Comment: @Krya, так и сделаю. Попробую. Спасибо